# CodeIgniter - sending to database table where items are checked in checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, html-table

I have a table in my application showing database records built using the codeigniter table library, and I send emails to the email addresses within the records.. currently it sends to all of the users contacts, but I have a column in the table with checkboxes using `array_unshift`.

My question is, how do I address in my model to send to Contacts where checkbox = checked?

Here is my table code in controller:

```
  function getDisplayUsersTable()
{
    // load model
    $this->load->model('Contacts_model');

    // load table library
    $this->load->library('table');

    // set table heading
    $this->table->set_heading('Check', 'Contact ID','Fullname', 'Email', 'Country', 'Gender', 'User_ID', 'Delete');

    // set table template
    $style = array('table_open'  => '<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">');
    $this->table->set_template($style);

    // call model function

$contacts = $this->Contacts_model->getUsers($this->session->user_id);

  $tableData = '';


  foreach($contacts as $contact) {          

    array_unshift($contact, '<input type="checkbox" label="check">');

    $this->table->add_row($contact);
  }

    // generate table from query result
    return $this->table->generate();

}
```

and here is my model code where i currently send to all of the users contacts they have saved

```
public function emailsend() {


  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT email from contacts WHERE users_id 
= '".$this->session->userdata('user_id')."'"); //select email addresses
  $sendTo=array();
  foreach ($query->result() as $row) //loop to build array

      $sendTo[]=$row->email; //add to array


return $sendTo;
```

button and form that sends email on front end

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('/Dashboard/sendmail');?>" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

<?php echo form_open('/Dashboard/sendmail');?>

  <label for="name">Your Name</label><input id="name" type="text" name="name">

  <label for="email">Your Email</label><input id="email" type="text" name="email">

  <button id="sendEmail" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light center-align" >Launch Campaign
  <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
    </button>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>

<p><?php echo $flash;?></p>


</form>
```

Comment: will there any button to send email after table.

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy i have edited question to show the form and button that currently sends the email to contacts